# Memory Leak Spotting

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I have the following code, and I am asked if there is any memory leak here.  I believe there is memory leak inside "function", because there is no delete operation after a = new A();  .  Am I right?

```
class A
{
 public:
   A(){};
   ~A(){};
 private:
   double d[10];
};

void function ( A* a)
{
    delete a;
    a = new A();
}

void main ( void)
{
  A* p = new A();
  function(p);
  delete p;
}
```

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: It's worse than just having a memory leak... you're also double-deleting the first allocation of A... once in function(A *a) and once in main().

Comment: And there is also a double delete because `p` is deleted twice, once in `function` and once in `main`.

Comment: The need to learn about and use smart pointers is strong with this one..

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question.  My understanding is that we are calling "function" using pass by pointer, which means that whatever changes we make on 'a' will affect 'p'.  Once we release a, we are also releasing p.  But after we release it, can we not reassign it?

Answer (score 1):

This program should crash **and** lose memory.

Crash because main releases memory `p` which was already released inside `function`.

Lose memory because `a` allocated in `function` is not being returned, and is internal to `function`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I think there is a misunderstanding of what happens.

You are right, that it is a pass-by-pointer. Which means that the address is pushed onto the stack of the callee function (or placed into a register, depends on the calling convention). And this address on the stack (or in the register) is used for freeing the the object. And finally this address will be overwritten with the address returned by new operator.

So **p** hasn't changed since it's in the stack of the caller not in the callee's.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  How can I fix this code?  Should I use smart pointers or references to avoid memory leak?